# The notification destination service region is not valid for the bucket location constraint when creating SQS Event on S3 Bucket via Cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I'm creating a cloudformation template which has to create a private bucket and then add event notification that send a message to a queue every time there's an object created in bucket. When i run the stack i get the following error:

The notification destination service region is not valid for the bucket location constraint (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument;

This is the template in Json format:

````
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "b4cec5e5-e02b-4489-80ee-9627fd1bbbff": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 40,
                    "y": 130
                },
                "z": 0,
                "embeds": [],
                "dependson": [
                    "8e5a0dc7-8982-475c-baa7-41de089beb18"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "S3B2HKY4": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
                "BucketName": "cloudformation.bucket.sqs",
                "AccessControl": "Private",
                "NotificationConfiguration": {
                    "QueueConfigurations": [
                        {
                            "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                            "Queue": "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:cloudformation_queue_s3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "b4cec5e5-e02b-4489-80ee-9627fd1bbbff"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```

I have checked similar problems but most of them are for SNS and Lambda function.
````

Answer (score 2):

Your `arn:aws:sqs:*:*:cloudformation_queue_s3` should be an absolute value (account and region).

The error is noted because the notifications from S3 event notifications must only be queued to resources in the same region as the bucket.

Comment: Thank you, that's why i was putting the stars because i'm doing this in a Dev environment and once it works i have to move it to a UAT environment then Production and that means i will have to constantly change the Regions and Account numbers when moving to different environment. But i will add the account and region, Thanks

Comment: No problem, you could just use `{"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:cloudformation_queue_s3"}` to add these in :)